# Dynamically created Dropdownlist inside Gridview doesnot fire event on second time

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been developing a webpage which uses n number of dropdownlists which are binding dynamically inside a gridview. I want to perform operations based on the dropdownlist's selectedindexchanged event. I had done that and working good, but when I changed dropdownlist on second time It does postback but not calls the event.

You can see my code here

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="gridDropDownTest.aspx.cs"
Inherits="gridDropDownTest" %><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head runat="server">    <title></title></head><body>    <form id="form1" runat="server">    <div>        <asp:GridView ID="gridLedgeDetails" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound"
        OnDataBound="gridLedgeDetails_DataBound">        </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form></body></html>


using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class gridDropDownTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        databind();
    }
    public void databind()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Mode");
        dt.Rows.Add("");
        dt.Rows.Add("");
        gridLedgeDetails.DataSource = dt;
        gridLedgeDetails.DataBind();
    }
    protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddlMode = new DropDownList();
            ddlMode.Width = 90;
            ddlMode.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:#ff6600;");
            ddlMode.Items.Add("Regular");
            ddlMode.Items.Add("Monthwise");
            ddlMode.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlMode_Indexchanged);
            ddlMode.AutoPostBack = true;
            ddlMode.ID = "ddlMode_";
            e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(ddlMode);
        }
    }
    protected void gridLedgeDetails_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
    protected void ddlMode_Indexchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uid = this.Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
        if (uid != null && uid.Contains("ddlMode_"))
        {
            string[] values = uid.Split('$');
            string row = values[1].Replace("ctl", "");
            Control ctrl = Page.FindControl(uid);
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)ctrl;
            if (ddl.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IAjc.png)

Comment: Minor tip, webforms are being deprecated. Meaning Asp.net 4.6 is the last versjon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to take and bind the dropdownlist again in Page_PreInit page method.

For Example....

protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

// here you need to build the gridview again.

// then the state will retain same......

}

Comment: I have been working through this for three days. Thank you